# Pattern matching function params

Tags: clojure, pattern-matching

I want `foo` to accept two params and if the first one is `:ok` it should return second param, otherwise first param.

I want to do it with pattern matching like this:

```clj
(defn foo [:ok val] (val))
(defn foo [key val] (key))
```

But it is not supported. Can I do it the similar way (using pattern matching or some kind of)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pattern matching functions in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596980/pattern-matching-functions-in-clojure)

Comment: @MartinPůda not really, because it uses conditional matching, but I want match with literal. I hope for my case there is more simple solution.

Comment: Your evaluation is conditional. The first pattern is tried before the second.

Answer (score 6):

if the pattern is not too complex, you can achieve something close to pattern matching using multimethods:

```clj
(defmulti foo (fn [key val] key))
(defmethod foo :default [key _] key)
(defmethod foo :ok [_ val] val)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `[patterned "0.2.0"]`

```
(require '[patterned.sweet :as p])
(p/defpatterned foo
    [:ok val] (val)
    [key val] (key))

(foo :ok +)
=> 0
(foo  * +)
=> 1
```

See [the pattern project](https://github.com/marick/patterned).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn foo
  [a b]
  (if (= :ok a)
    b
    a))

(verify
  (is= (foo :ok   :something) :something)
  (is= (foo :nope :something) :nope))
```

If there were more than 2 cases, you may want to use a `(cond ...)` form.

Built using [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).